# How can I install .NET 2.0 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, .net-2.0

I am trying to install Web Matrix on my Windows 7 machine.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

When I click on "Install WebMatrix", the installer complains that .NET 2.0 is not installed. So it tries to install .NET 2.0 . However, installing .NET 2.0 fails because Windows 7 already has .NET 2.0.

Got it? me neither.

I tried uninstalling .NET 3.5 feature. Same problem. Then reinstall. Same problem.

Any advice? (other than "Windows 7 already includes .NET 2.0")

Answer (score 1):

Have you uninstalled the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 feature in "Programs and Features"? .NET 2.0 is included in this (because 3.5 is 2.0 with extensions).

Comment: Yes, I have uninstalled and reinstalled .NET framework 3.5 feature in "Programs and Features". No effect

Comment: Try removing .NET 3.5 and then cleaning it completely with http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx

Comment: this tool does not remove .net 2.0 from windows 7